# Select from my tabel where date = specific date

Tags: mysql, date

My date in table is `TIMESTAMP` something like this `2016-05-28 18:39:00`

Now I am trying to select from table where date = `2016-05-28`

here is my query

```
    $getReport = $db->prepare('SELECT a.proId, a.userId, DATE(a.date), a.status, a.canceledBy, b.id, b.pName, b.pPrice FROM purchaseshistory AS a INNER JOIN products AS b ON(a.proId=b.id) WHERE a.date=?');

    $getReport->bind_param('i', $dateOfBirth);
    $getReport->execute();
    $getReport->bind_result($proId, $userId, $date, $status, $canceledBy, $id, $pName, $pPrice);
$getReport->store_result();
while ($getReport->fetch()) {
```

Date is coming from here

```
$dateOfBirth = $_POST['dateOfBirth'];
```

results are empty

Comment: you'd need to do `were date(a.date) = ?`, to make sure you're comparing dates to dates. Otherwise mysql is free to extend your posted data to havea  `00:00:00` time, and only match that EXACT date/time

Comment: @Marc B I try this too but still the results are empty, the print of the var `$dateOfBirth` is `28-05-2016` and the record in the table is `2016-05-28 18:39:00`

Comment: then that's why. mysql only considers strings to be dates if they're in `yyyy-mm-dd` format. anything else is just random numbers/characters, and string matching rules get applied. that means `'2016-05-28' = '28-05-2016'` is FALSE, because they're different STRINGS, even though most humans might recognize them both as dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could be you need a correct date format

```
SELECT a.proId, a.userId, 
DATE(a.date), a.status, a.canceledBy, b.id, b.pName, b.pPrice 
FROM purchaseshistory AS a 
INNER JOIN products AS b ON(a.proId=b.id) 
WHERE date_format(a.date,'%Y-%m-%d') = ?
```

Comment: Yes thanks this is it understood I just changed the format to be `date_format(a.date,'%d-%m-%Y') = ?` thanks worked

Comment: just waiting for the 4 minutes to pass to accept you answer thanks again :)

Comment: Why use date_format when you can just use `date(?)`? Also be wary of timezone differences between your client and your servers.

Answer (score 0):

You've converted a.date to a DATE in the SELECT, but not in the WHERE clause, I would recommend modifying your query as below:

```
SELECT 
  ph.proId, ph.userId, DATE(ph.date), ph.status, ph.canceledBy,
  p.id, p.pName, p.pPrice 
FROM purchaseshistory AS ph 
  INNER JOIN products AS p ON ph.proId = p.id
WHERE DATE(ph.date) = ?
```